# PHP/MYSQL Coloring names

Tags: php, mysql

I'm searching for ideas how to color names. So I've got database with user information and user color code(#000 or etc.). Bellow is code which makes drop-dow list of users. I need to color user names by the color code which i added to database. Where could I put the code in? Names are in **Owner filter**

```
<font color="<?php echo @$user['user_color'];?>"></font>
```

And here is the code which prints the list of users.

```
//db_loadHashList($sql);
$owner_combo = arraySelect($owner_list, 'owner_filter_id', 
                           'class="text" onchange="javascript:document.searchform.submit()"', 
                           $owner_filter_id, false);
// setup the title block
$titleBlock = new CTitleBlock('Companies', 'handshake.png', $m, "$m.$a");
$titleBlock->addCell(('<form name="searchform" action="?m=companies&amp;search_string=' 
                      . dPformSafe($search_string) . '" method="post">' . "\n" 
                      . '<table><tr><td><strong>' . $AppUI->_('Search') 
                      . '</strong><input class="text" type="text" name="search_string" value="' 
                      .  dPformSafe($search_string) . '" /><br />' 
                      . '<a href="index.php?m=companies&amp;search_string=-1">' 
                      . $AppUI->_('Reset search') . '</a></td><td valign="top"><strong>' 
                      . $AppUI->_('Owner filter').'</strong> ' . $owner_combo 
                      . ' </td></tr></table></form>'));
```

Sample:

Lenon, John(red)

Steve, Mickey(yellow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop trying to note down the color on every single element you create in your view. Use classes instead, classes exist to identify groups of element to received identical styling rules.

Instead you should create a dynamic style sheet file (css file) where for each user a color is defined:

```
.....
.user-styled.user-53846298 { color: #643; }
.user-styled.user-45384763 { color: #765; }
.user-styled.user-65937405 { color: #AB7; }
.....
```

Such file can be created on-the-fly by means of php when requested just like any ordinary, static css file.

Then, inside your view creation routines you mark those elements associated with a specific user by a) the fact that it should receive user specific styling and b) the is of the specific user:

```
.....
<form name="searchform" .....>
    .....
    <select name="search_user" .....>
        <option 
            class="user-styled user-<?= $user['user_id']?>"
            value="<?= $user['user_id'] ?>">
            <?= $user['user_name'] ?>
        </option>
        .....
    </select>
    .....
</form>
.....
```

This approach is not limited to certain element types or anything. It is flexible, powerful and performs fine, since the dynamically created style definition can be cached just like any other css file. It also allows to apply the same styling without additional effort to dynamic content created by means of client side scripting or ajax calls. So if you fetch additional information about a single user you don't have to know about that users color (or whatever user specific data), since it already is present in the style definition. You just mark the user id to the element and they will get rendered accordingly.

Comment: So where can i add         
<option 
            class="user-styled user-<?= $user['user_id']?>"
            value="<?= $user['user_id'] ?>">
            <?= $user['user_name'] ?></option>

If i cant find option values in files

Comment: I only used a n option select element with its option children as an example. As written above you can use this approach for any html element, so also for text inputs, radio buttons, textareas, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use styles in your select box then is best to use some jQuery for this. `<select>` elements are hard to style with CSS directly.

See for your solution: http://gregfranko.com/jquery.selectBoxIt.js/

Comment: Can you explain me a bit, where can i use it?